# Как создать такой массив кодом?

Tags: c#, массивы

Хочу создать такой массив программно. Спасибо.

```
Array
    (
        ["spawns"] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        ["pos"] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 254
                                [1] => 54
                                [2] => 500
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: `List<List<int>>`. Если имена имеют значения, то используйте словарь (Dictionary).

Comment: `Array["spawns"[pos[0]]]` - такой синтаксис в C# невозможен.

Comment: так как представлен не массив, можно представить такой структурой: `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string,List<int>>>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Показанной в вопросе структуре соответствует следующее:

```
var Array = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, List<int>>>>
{
    ["spawns"] = new List<Dictionary<string, List<int>>>
    {
        new Dictionary<string, List<int>>
        {
            ["pos"] = new List<int>
            {
                254, 54, 500
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Обращаться так:

```
var n = Array["spawns"][0]["pos"][0];
```